# unix: main() interactive, command line, piping & redirection in C?

Tags: c, unix, command-line

While there is an easy way of using both **file redirection** and **piping**, as well as interactive user input reading , with ***main()***, as shown in this C code snippet...

```c
#define  SIZ 1024
#include <stdio.h>
extern void do_something_with_the_array(float *a[], int *n);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    float f[SIZ];
    int k = 0;
    while ((scanf("%f", &f[k]) == 1)&&(k < SIZ)) {
      k++;
    }
    do_something_with_the_array(f, k);
    return 0;
}
```

… I'm not sure if there is a modern UNIX source compatible and easy way of programmatically achieving any of the three possibilities in a `main()` in **C**, depending on the context ?

- interactive reading of a string of numbers as user input
- reading of the same string of numbers as command line arguments
- file redirection and piping

I understand piping and redirection "belong" to the shell which intercepts the program before it even starts executing, while command line arguments and interactive reading "belong" to the ***main()*** itself and therefore there may not be an easy way of doing this.

I see using **stdin** or **file** input or **pipe** input pretty self-explanatory. However, reading command line arguments is a different story. Here's a demo how I usually code it, but it looks kind of heavy-handed and hacked to me. Also, in more complicated scenarios with options, this could become a pretty messy piece of code. I'm also not sure how fail-safe or fool proof this is...

```
#define  SIZ 1024
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
extern void do_something_with_the_array(float *, int);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    float f[SIZ];
    int k = 0;
    if(argc > 2){
        for(k = 0; k < argc - 1; k++) 
            f[k] = (float)atof(argv[k+1]);
    }
    else while ((scanf("%f", &f[k]) == 1)&&(k < SIZ))
        k++;

    do_something_with_the_array(f, k);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The snipped you posted might potentially overflow.

Comment: Why would these things not be possible?  Simply write  switch statement to handle the three conditions.

Comment: The program does not usually know whether `stdin` refers to a terminal console, a file, a socket, or any other stream you could think of.

Comment: would someone please be so kind explaining what is wrong about asking this question please?

Comment: @user3078414: The snippet of code only uses `stdin`. It does not illustrate what else you expect to do, and neither does the rest of the question.

Comment: @user3078414, the answer is yes :)

Comment: Thanks, @EOF, I'm improving my question right now, following your kind suggestion.

Comment: @Leandros, thanks. I'm aware this may well overflow. The declaration is oversimplified just for clarity. In interactive reading, the right way would be to first check against valid input and then realloc the array with each new valid input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know off-hand of a C library that will make the three specific cases you mentioned look the same (although someone who does, please answer because I'd like to know, too!).  I think you're looking for something not unlike [the diamond `<>` operator in Perl](http://perlmaven.com/the-diamond-operator), but for individual arguments rather than files containing arguments.

I think @David Hoelzer has the right idea: handle the three cases separately.  For example, when processing command-line or file arguments, don't generate "Enter a value" prompts that you might print for interactive input.  For command-line processing, [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt) is a good place to start.

Now, a challenge to you: Wrap those three operations in a library and make it open-source so the rest of us can benefit! :)

Comment: thanks @cxw. I knew `getopt()` used to be a part of gnu-C. I've checked, it's a part of NetBSD (Darwin, OSX) as well. Some tests give promising results. I accept this answer as most helpful in finding solution to my question. If I have a chance of successfully writing a proposed library, I'll surely publish it open-source!

Comment: @user3078414 Many thanks, and good luck to you!  If you think of it, once you publish, comment back with the link and I'll check it out :) .

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few programs do care if they're invoked with keyboard input vs. file input, including the shell itself.

Let us take /bin/sh as our first example. If you call it directly, it starts an interactive shell, but if you pipe something into it, it starts as a non-interactive reading shell. The main difference between the two is if it is not interactive, it doesn't display the $ prompt. However just in case it really is interactive, it can be started with the -i option to make it assume its interactive when it would normally decide otherwise.

The magic involved here is `isatty()`; see `man 3 isatty`.

In addition, some programs like to receive keyboard input while processing redirected standard input. There are two generally favored ways of doing this; either opening and reading from `/dev/tty` or reading standard error, depending on context. Most stuff in an interactively started pipeline doesn't have standard error redirected, so this tends to work well (reading a redirected standard error yields an error immediately as the handle isn't open for read). If you want to make it potentially fully automatable, you read standard error, otherwise you read `/dev/tty`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. I am also "on this track". For the moment, I'm studying signal handling in all the cases, since some of the programs I'm writing to comply with this requirement also do some very intensive number crunching and have real-time-priority threads.